# Operator Overloading, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++

I am doing some practice about operator overloading, but I got some problem. `class Rational2` protected inheritance `class Rational` 
And I finish the overloading. I am a beginner, please help, thank you.

The error is this.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Rational2 const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main2.o
  "operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Rational2 const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

XCODE cannot find the error before I build it.
Why would it be like that? Do I use the wrong way to overloading
Or there are some problems with `class Rational`?

Comment: Please copy the errors you get, as text and in full and complete. Then edit your question to paste it without any modifications.

Comment: Do you know what a [MVCE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) is? There is a lot of code here that I don't think is 100% relevant to tracking down your problem.